# Search Kit - related contacts query

Tags: searchkit

Hoping for some Search Kit advice / guidance.

I have a search that brings in various contacts as outlined below:

- Contact 1 (Individual) - the volunteer - has associated custom data
  and a relationship to
- Contact 2 (Organisation) - has a relationship to
- Contact 3 (Service Manager)

I can bring in the first two without issues but don't seem to bring in the 3 contact when I start with the individual as contact 1 (as no relationship to 3 I suspect).

However if I flip it and start with above contact 2 (the organisation) I am able to bring in all the contacts necessary and filter contact 3 to current user only - however, I need to display custom data associated with contact 1 which I can't do when I start the search with contact 2 as the main contact.

Is there a Search Kit guru that can help as I could just miss something obvious, added the SQL for my queries below.

**Unable to bring in the service manager (to filter)**

```
SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`display_name` AS `display_name`, `Volunteer__1`.`type_of_volunteer_64` AS `Volunteer_.Type_of_volunteer:label`, `Volunteer__1`.`vol_start_date_128` AS `Volunteer_.Vol_Start_Date`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `far_contact_id_2`.`display_name` SEPARATOR "") AS `GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01_far_contact_id_display_name`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `near_contact_id_3`.`display_name` SEPARATOR "") AS `GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_RelationshipCache_far_contact_id_01_near_contact_id_display_name`
FROM civicrm_contact a
INNER JOIN `civicrm_relationship_cache` `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01` ON `a`.`id` = `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`near_contact_id` AND `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`near_relation` = "Volunteer of"
INNER JOIN `civicrm_relationship_cache` `Contact_RelationshipCache_far_contact_id_01` ON `a`.`id` = `Contact_RelationshipCache_far_contact_id_01`.`far_contact_id` AND `Contact_RelationshipCache_far_contact_id_01`.`near_relation` = "Service Manager for"
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_value_volunteer__15` `Volunteer__1` ON `a`.`id` =  `Volunteer__1`.`entity_id`
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_contact` `far_contact_id_2` ON `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`far_contact_id` =  `far_contact_id_2`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_contact` `near_contact_id_3` ON `Contact_RelationshipCache_far_contact_id_01`.`near_contact_id` =  `near_contact_id_3`.`id`
WHERE (`a`.`is_deleted` = "0")
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`sort_name` ASC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

**Able to filter**

```
SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`display_name` AS `display_name`, `near_contact_id_1`.`display_name` AS `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01.near_contact_id.display_name`, `far_contact_id_2`.`display_name` AS `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01.far_contact_id.display_name`, `far_contact_id_3`.`display_name` AS `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02.far_contact_id.display_name`, `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`near_contact_id` AS `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01.near_contact_id`, `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`relationship_id` AS `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01.relationship_id`, `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`orientation` AS `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01.orientation`, `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02`.`near_contact_id` AS `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02.near_contact_id`, `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02`.`relationship_id` AS `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02.relationship_id`, `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02`.`orientation` AS `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02.orientation`
FROM civicrm_contact a
INNER JOIN `civicrm_relationship_cache` `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01` ON `a`.`id` = `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`near_contact_id` AND `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`near_relation` = "Service Manager is" AND `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`far_contact_id` = "39260"
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_relationship_cache` `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02` ON `a`.`id` = `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02`.`near_contact_id` AND `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02`.`near_relation` = "Volunteer is"
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_contact` `near_contact_id_1` ON `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`near_contact_id` =  `near_contact_id_1`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_contact` `far_contact_id_2` ON `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_01`.`far_contact_id` =  `far_contact_id_2`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_contact` `far_contact_id_3` ON `Contact_RelationshipCache_near_contact_id_02`.`far_contact_id` =  `far_contact_id_3`.`id`
WHERE (`a`.`is_deleted` = "0")
ORDER BY `a`.`sort_name` ASC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

As per Aidan's answer below - achievable with a later version of CiviCRM (I was on 5.49)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add Contact 3, select the entry 'Contact Related Contacts' that is indented under 'Contact Related Contacts' so that the relationship is to Contact 2 not Contact 1.

If you filter by 'related' you can see the options more clearly:

[image]

Comment: I have no indented option there. Maybe I just need a newer version?

Comment: The screenshot was from dmaster currently on 5.54.alpha1 but that feature has been around for a while.

Comment: The normal indentation is 20px but with Shoreditch theme, it's reduced to 10px. On my big screen, I barely see it.

Comment: I thought I should be able to follow the above but missing something. goal is to have who ever views this to see "the local group they manage" and therefore "all the contacts related to their local group". It sounds like your answer got Rebecca what she needed but something does not make sense to me

Comment: and even if i did, would i then be able to 'add them to an event' or am i better fixing up drupal 9 VBO do this this via Views?

Comment: hmm. ok i did have the SK built as required (was testing as wrong user), but no options to 'add contacts to event' that i can see. perhaps these Actions are yet to come?